# cannot pass multiple variables through javascript from an onclick command

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I have a php script that outputs this code, but only the first variable will alert.  I have tried to remove the quotes, but It will only reply the first variable.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

function add_reply(a,b,c,d){

    alert(a,b,c,d);

}


</script>

</head>

<body>

<input type="button" onclick="add_reply('reply3','3','8006549654','49')">


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Working as designed.  `alert` is a method that takes one argument, not 4.  Try concatenating the arguments together

Comment: alert show only first variable as per your code, try to alert for each variable, it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function add_reply(a,b,c,d){

    alert(a+" "+b+" "+c+" "+d);

}
```

Only one argument is allowed in `alert()` method . Concatenate all variables or use multiple alert method . First process is better in my opinion .